# How to use Bootrstrap error styling within CodeIgniter form validation?

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem with my code. I am studying bootstrap CSS. And I am so amaze with this framework. That's why I decided to study this. I don't really don't have enough knowledge in CSS. But I understand a little.

I am creating a form and I want to have a validation message if username or password are wrong.. I have a validation of required. But after creating my validation and passing to the model. I don't know how can I display again to the same page and display my error message?

Here's my simple code.

In my controller

```
class Admin extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/adminauth');
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['title'] = "Administration";

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('header/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('contents/login',$data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer');

        } else {

            $validate_login = $this->adminauth->validate_login();

            if($validate_login > 0) {



            } else {

                            //this should be go back again to the index and display my error message.
                $this->index();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

In my view I have this

```
<div class="panel-body form-admin-signin">

    <?php 
        $form_array = array(
            'class' => 'form-signin'
        );
        echo form_open('admin',$form_array); 
    ?>
        <div class="form-group">

            <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Username</h3>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control inputs" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"  />
                <?php echo form_error('username','<div class="error_msg">','</div>'); ?>
            <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Password</h3>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control inputs" placeholder="password" value=""  />
                <?php echo form_error('password','<div class="error_msg">','</div>'); ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" /> Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary login-btn" value="Login" />

        </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    <?php   
            //THIS IS I WANT TO DISPLAY. IF INVALID THE CHECKING IN SQL IT WILL DISPLAY BELOW THE FORM
        $validate = '';
        if($validate == 1) {
    ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <label>Invalid Username or Password please try again!</label>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

</div>
```

In my model I have this

```
class AdminAuth extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate_login() {

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

        $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";
        $get_result = $this->db->query($query);

        return $get_result->num_rows();

    }

}
```

That's all guys, I hope you can help me. Or can you give me an example using AJAX with this?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error while sending enquiry email.');
$this->index();
```

or you can use :-

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error while sending enquiry email.');
redirect('contoller');
```

on view :-

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `$data['errors']` variable in your controller within

`if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {`

add

`$data['errors'] = validation_errors();`

and at the top of your view file add

```
<?php if(isset($errors)){ ?>
     <div class="alert alert-danger"> <!--bootstrap error div-->
          <?=$errors?>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sorry I got an error like this after submitting wrong data.

 `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\hommeetfemme\system\libraries\Log.php on line 79`

Comment: Don't copy and paste the exact code from above, it's not complete the if statement is not closed.